# C Memory Leak passing argument?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-leaks

So my gcc compiler says:

```
=================================================================
==831==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60c000001d3c at pc 0x7fcb29c87075 bp 0x7ffe0bf63e70 sp 0x7ffe0bf635e8
READ of size 121 at 0x60c000001d3c thread T0
```

I pass an char *list = argv[1] into a function. could this be the reason of this?

Comment: The sanitizer says you have a buffer overflow, not a memory leak. By the way, having two variables named `sl` and `s1` is potentially confusing.

Comment: `s1` is never used either

Comment: In `WriteAfterMathData` the indentation does not match the braces `{`...`}`. Is this your real code or did you accidentally remove a brace? Without knowing the structure definitions, how you allocate the memory and what exactly you pass to the functions it is difficult to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @Blastfurnace so where should i look at? I read in a dynamic value in the main via  char *name = argv[4]; and pass that to RemoveCity as an argument. Do you think this might could cause that? As for the others: fclose is outside the iteration, but i can't edit my post for some reasons (it says it contains mostly code now). s1 was just for debugging purposes.

Comment: You're likely reading/writing past the end of an array or you have an invalid pointer. I would run the code in a debugger, put a breakpoint at the `fprintf`, and look at your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're closing your file multiple times.

```
for (int i = 1; i < sl->count; i++)
{
    if (sl->stadt[i]->stadtId != s->stadtId)
    {
        s1 = sl->stadt[i];
        fprintf(file, "%d %s %d \n", sl->stadt[i]->stadtId, sl->stadt[i]->name, sl->stadt[i]->gebietId);
    }
fclose(file); // Being called several times on the loop!
}
```

As you can see, the fclose(file) is inside the for loop, and from what i can see, it is called several times, that's what may be causing the issue.

What you can do:
In case you want to close the file after printing in the file, you can put your fclose(file) inside the if statement and interrupt the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < sl->count; i++)
{
    if (sl->stadt[i]->stadtId != s->stadtId)
    {
        s1 = sl->stadt[i];
        fprintf(file, "%d %s %d \n", sl->stadt[i]->stadtId, sl->stadt[i]->name, sl->stadt[i]->gebietId);
        fclose(file);
        break;
    }
}
```

If the print is called multiple times, you just need to move the fclose(file) out of the for loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < sl->count; i++)
{
    if (sl->stadt[i]->stadtId != s->stadtId)
    {
        s1 = sl->stadt[i];
        fprintf(file, "%d %s %d \n", sl->stadt[i]->stadtId, sl->stadt[i]->name, sl->stadt[i]->gebietId);
    }
}
fclose(file);
```